# Extract held value from Association

Tags: evaluation, associations, hold

Consider an association which contains a key which must not be prematurely evaluated.

```
assoc = <| key :> value |>
```

For example, a value of `a[[b]]` would throw a `Part` error until symbols `a` and `b` are substituted.

We might wish to obtain this value in its unevaluated form, e.g. to display. Simply calling

```
assoc[key]
```

will evaluate `value` (and in that example, throw a `Part` error).

One trick is to exploit that matched patterns are unevaluated:

```
assoc /. KeyValuePattern[ key :> v_ ] -> Hold[v]
```

but this seems needlessly hacky for what must be a common operation.
What's the right way to obtain `Hold[value]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ironically, the probably simplest answer is literally `Extract`, just as in the question's title:

```
Extract[assoc, {Key[key]}, Hold]

(* Hold[value] *)
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a [Lookup](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) variant that supports wrapping with a head before evaluation:

```
Lookup[assoc, key, Missing[], Hold]
```

Comment: Note this requires v12.1 (incompatible with my 11.1)